# Saving vim state with mksession will not save Ctrl-6 state

Tags: vim, editor, savestate

When I save my vim session using :mksession mysavedsession, it saves everthing that is relevant to me except for the swapped buffer opened in each of my vim windows brought to view by Ctrl-6.

Any easy solutions to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's `<C-^>`, not `<C-6>`.

I don't think that there's such a thing as a "`<C-^>` state": `<C-^>` is used to edit the previously edited file but it doesn't have a "hard" value. When you are restoring a session you haven't edited any previous file so it's likely that `<C-^>` doesn't work. Just like there's no "previous file" if you just started Vim.

A quick look at `:help mksession`, `:help mkview`, `:help sessionoptions` and `:help viewoptions` doesn't seem to indicate any workaround.